# Spring Webflux application, unable to get reactor.netty.http.client* metrics and reactor.netty.connection.provider* metrics

Tags: java, netty, spring-webflux

Small question regarding metrics with a Spring Webflux 2.4.2 application.

The application is a server, and during processing, uses the Webflux Webclient in order to perform outbound HTTP requests.

Now, I am looking at this page here: https://projectreactor.io/docs/netty/release/reference/index.html#_metrics_5

Mainly, I can see those kinds of metrics:

1 - the reactor.netty.http.client.data* metrics

2 - the reactor.netty.connection.provider* metrics

3 - the reactor.netty.bytebuf.allocator.used* metrics

I am only able to get the third group, the reactor.netty.bytebuf.allocator.used* metrics.

How to, what configurations are needed to get the first two types please?

I am already doing:

```
  @Bean
    public NettyServerCustomizer nettyServerCustomizer() {
        return httpServer -> httpServer.metrics(true, () -> new MicrometerChannelMetricsRecorder("myService", "myService"));
    }
```

and this in my main method `Schedulers.enableMetrics();`

I am really wondering how to get the first two types, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first metric in your list are metrics published by the client and the second is published by the connection provider. Neither are related to the HttpServer. As a result, you need to enable these metrics in your Tcp/HttpClient/ConnectionProvider. This is exposed in a similar way to the HttpServer.

**HttpClient Example**

```
HttpClient.create().metrics(true, uriTagValueFunction)
```

**TcpClient Example**

```
TcpClient.create().metrics(true)
```

**Connection Provider Example**

```
ConnectionProvider.builder(poolName).metrics(true).build()
```

[HttpClient JavaDocs](https://projectreactor.io/docs/netty/release/api/reactor/netty/http/client/HttpClient.html#metrics-boolean-java.util.function.Function-)

[TcpClient JavaDocs](https://projectreactor.io/docs/netty/release/api/index.html?reactor/netty/tcp/TcpClient.html)

[ConnectionProvider JavaDocs](https://projectreactor.io/docs/netty/release/api/index.html?reactor/netty/resources/ConnectionProvider.html)

Comment: So, this is very strange. I added HttpClient.create().metrics(true, uriTagValueFunction), and it worked. (Upvote)

Comment: But it is not working as I expect, I now have reactor.netty.connection.provider* and reactor.netty.bytebuf.allocator.used*

Comment: But not the reactor.netty.http.client.data* metrics, which is what I was looking for

Comment: do you mind double checking this? By enabling metrics on the http client I can see the `reactor.netty.http.client.data.*` metrics when I hit the `/actuator/metrics` endpoint of my demo app

Comment: Two weeks of monitoring and gathering the metrics, sadly, I can still see the last two, but not the first one

Comment: I am accepting the answer, and will open an issue, just to ask why the first type is not here